# Hide mobile browser video content when screen lock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I want to hide video content when screen locked.

The red circle in the picture below is what I want to hide.

To be precise, I want the red circle not to appear when document.visibilityState == 'hidden'.

Here is my code.

```js
$(document).on('visibilitychange', function(){
   if(document.visibilityState == 'hidden'){
    video.pause();
   }
  })
```

How should I change my code?

[image]

I'm using a plain video tag like this.

`<video muted id="video" poster="" src="" webkit-playsinline playsinline>
                </video>`

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the relevant component?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to hide an element when some event runs. I'm using the 'click' event, but you can substitute in your code as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hide Element</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <h1>Hide Me</h1>
  <button>Click to Mimic Visibility Change</button>

  <script>

    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      h1.classList.toggle('hide');
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dayun123/1pxay64b/) you can use to try it out.